# Изменение value по клику на radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Какую функцию нужно написать, чтобы по клику на radio "Москва" значение value="" стало тоже Москвой?

```html
<input type="radio" id="client-city"><lable></lable>
<lable id="city" for="client-city">Москва</lable>

<p><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Адрес" id="address" value=""></p>
```

Задача заключается в том, чтобы исходный код не менять, а добавить функционал через тэг script

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#client-city').change(function() {
  $('#address').val($('#city').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="client-city"><lable></lable>
<lable id="city" for="client-city">Москва</lable>

<p><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Адрес" id="address"></p>
```

Либо без jQuery:

```html
<input type="radio" id="client-city" onchange="document.getElementById('address').value = document.getElementById('city').innerHTML"><lable></lable>
<lable id="city" for="client-city">Москва</lable>

<p><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Адрес" id="address"></p>
```

Comment: первый вариант помог, а так чтобы не ('#city'), а подставлялось именно текстом Москва?

Comment: все, разобрался. Спасибо!

Comment: Тогда просто изменять на текст, а не брать его из других блоков.